# Changing variable names at runtime in objective-c / iPhone

Tags: objective-c, variables, uiimageview, nsmutablearray, while-loop

I have a loop that counts how many items are in an array, then I need to create a UIView based on the index that is currently being referenced at that instant. For example I have:

```
int itn2 = 0;
    while(itn2 < [imageLinks count]){
//imageLinks is my NSMutableArray
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageLinks objectAtIndex:itn2]];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

I need the UIImageView that I allocate to have a name based on the current integer itn2 (0) like:

```
    [viewVar%i,itn2] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

so as the loop changes from say 0 to 2, I will have 3 UIViews, called viewVar0, viewVar1, viewVar2, how can I do this?? I'm used to matlab where I can just do viewVar(itn2).

Comment: No, never use index as part of variable name. In this case, just use an array to store those views, and let the array provide you the index. Or use a dictionary, depends on your actual situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create variables on-the-fly easily.

I'd use a mutable array to hold the `UIImageViews`:

```
NSMutableArray *imageViews = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[imageLinks count]];
for(NSUInteger i=0; i < [imageLinks count]; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[imageLinks objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [imageViews addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
}
```

Then, use `[imageViews objectAtIndex:0]` for the first one, etc. 
If this is something you'll do a lot in your app, you can add a macro like this:

```
#define IV(idx) (idx < [imageViews count] ? [imageViews objectAtIndex:idx] : nil)
```

in order to write `[someView addSubview:IV(0)]` or whatever you need. But I don't recommend it.

(Note: you'll need to `autorelease` some stuff if you aren't using ARC)

Comment: usually objectAtIndex: calls are not needed, avoid unless you know you need them.: NSMutableArray *imageViews = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSURL* aLink in imageLinks) {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aLink];
    [imageViews addObject:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
}